# semaphore and memory ordering

Tags: c++, semaphore, c++20

Does `std::counting_semaphore` from C++20 behave like a mutex / atomic operation?
*i.e.* is `semaphore.acquire()` an acquire operation (regarding the memory ordering), and is `semaphore.release()` a release operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acquire and release memory operations ultimately define "happens before" relationships between executions, and it is the "happens before" relationship that permits observing side effects.

`counting_semaphore::release` bypasses acquire/release semantics by [just declaring that](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/thread.sema.cnt#10) the `release` call "strongly happens before" any `try_acquire` (which all forms of `acquire` are built on) which observes the effects of this `release` statement.

> Strongly happens before invocations of `try_­acquire` that observe the result of the effects.

So that provides all the synchronization you need for an `acquire` to be able to observe side effects from `release` calls.